# How to update Elasticsearch documents by Primary Key matching?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I’ve 2 indexes on ElasticSearch viz.

1. Orignial_index has a set of records, sample below. It has around 300 million documents
2. Updated_index has a few updated values. Around 90 million documents are updated
   I want to update the documents in Original_index. URL is the primary key through which mapping can be done.
   I want to understand, how this can be done?

Index 1: Orginial_Index

```json
{"url":"”www.domain.com/bret”","id":1,"name":"Leanne Graham","username":"Bret","email":"Sincere@april.biz","street":"Kulas Light","suite":"Apt. 556","city":"Gwenborough","zipcode":"92998-3874","geo":{"lat":"-37.3159","lng":"81.1496"}}
```

Index 2: Updated_Index:

```json
{"url":"”www.domain.com/bret”","email":"Leanne@march.biz","street":"Dummy Road","suite":"Dummy Suit","city":"Gwenborough","zipcode":"748596","geo":{"lat":"-55.3159","lng":"44.1496"}}
```

Documents from updated_index need to be updated in Original_index
Resultant Index records will be as below:

```json
{"url":"”www.domain.com/bret”","id":1,"name":"Leanne Graham","username":"Bret","email":" Leanne@march.biz ","street":" Dummy Road ","suite":" Dummy Suit ","city":"Gwenborough","zipcode":"748596","geo":{"lat":"-55.3159","lng":"44.1496"}}
```

I tried using Update By Query API, but was not able to run in properly
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html

Comment: what is value of `_id` field when you are indexing document into elasticsearch ?

Comment: '_id'  is autogenerated and stored, nothing which I am doing separately..

Comment: I think so then you can not do with update by query or reindex api. You need to write custom script in java or python to handle this.